# Dropdown menu overflow issue: Mouseenter and Mouseleave + slideDown and slideUp

Tags: jquery, css

I have this simple dropdown menu with sub menus.
Problem is that when I hover the menu item to show its submenu(with slideDown), it only shows part of the menu while the animation/effect is running(overflow issue) - When the animation is complete, only then the whole menu is displayed

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GM9Lm/45/) to see what I mean:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="main">
    <li><a>Item1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>subItem1</li>
            <li>subItem2</li>
            <li>subItem3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Item2</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>subItem4</li>
            <li>subItem5</li>
            <li>subItem6</li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li><a>Item3</a></li>
    <li><a>Item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
ul#main li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}
ul#main li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
ul.sub{
    position: relative; 
    top: 100%; 
    right: 30%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

ul.sub li{
    float: none;    
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('ul#main li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children('ul.sub').slideDown(300);
});
$('ul#main li').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children('ul.sub').slideUp(300);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add width to `ul.sub` see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/GM9Lm/46/

Comment: thanks, but look what it does when you change the width to 100px...why is it floating by sub list items? - http://jsfiddle.net/GM9Lm/58/

Comment: yes then you may need to add ul#main before ul.sub li because float none will not work as previously defined with ID. Please take a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/GM9Lm/60/

Comment: oh yes...where is my CSS manners...Cascading... id enjoys more privilege than class...thanks for your help, appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Add width to your `ul.sub`:

```
ul.sub{
    position: relative; 
    top: 100%; 
    right: 30%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 50px;
}
```

To fix issue with floating items add also:

```
ul.sub li{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but look what it does when you change the width to 100px...why is it floating by sub list items? - http://jsfiddle.net/GM9Lm/58/

Comment: I improved my answer to fix this issue